# Open Mapping Theorem from $C^n$ to $C^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, several-complex-variables

I am looking for an Open Mapping Theorem for a holomorphic function $f: U \subset \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^n$ where $U$ is a domain. I believe the following is true:

> Let $f: U \subset \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^n$ be holomorphic, where $U$ is a domain. Suppose the determinant of the Jacobian of $f$ is not identically zero on $U$. Then $f(U)$ is open.

References and thoughts are welcome.

Comment: @user251257 I'm not sure - I would definitely agree with you if we instead assumed the determinant of the Jacobian is nonvanishing

Comment: ah, I misunderstood your statement

Answer (score 2):

Not true: $(x,y)\mapsto(x, xy)$.

Comment: The map provided is an open map.  This is not a counterexample.

Comment: Denote the given map by $f$. I show it is not open at $(0,0)$. Let $r_1<1$. I show that for any $r_2>0$, there exists $z,w\in B_{r_2}(0)$ such that $(z,w)\not\in f(B_{r_1}(0)\times B_{r_1}(0))$.  Indeed, choose $z=r_2r_1, w=r_2$, then the only solution is $x=r_2r_1, y=1/r_1$.