# Does the Open Mapping Theorem hold for invertible holomorphic function of several variables?

Tags: several-complex-variables

Suppose there is a holomorphic function $\mathbf{f}:U\rightarrow V$ with several complex variables, where $U$ and $V$ are both open sets in $\mathbb{C}^n$. If the Jacobian matrix of $\mathbf{f}$ on $x_0$, $\mathbf{Df}(x_0)$ is invertible, then we can conclude that $\mathbf{f}$ has an inverse function in a neighborhood $U’$ of $x_0$. Can I immediately conclude that $\mathbf{f}(U’)$ is open?

This question is not the same as [Open Mapping Theorem from $C^n$ to $C^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1662690). The difference is the condition about Jacobian matrix. Mine is that Jacobian matrix on a point is invertible, but his/hers is that Jacobian matrix is not identically zero on $U$.

Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: This is a special case of the invariance of domain theorem.

Comment: No. I have read that. First, no one gave a proof. Second, the counterexample is not right since the determinant of Jacobian matrix at 0 is zero. @BrevanEllefsen

Comment: I'm voting to reopen since this post is not a duplicate of [Open Mapping Theorem from $C^n$ to $C^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1662690), for the reason stated by OP.